# Splitting semicolon separated string in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a semicolon separated string so that I can store each individual string to be used as text between XML tags using Python. The string value looks like this:

```
08-26-2009;08-27-2009;08-29-2009
```

They are just dates stored as string values

I want to iterate through each value, store to a variable and call the variable into the following code at the end:

```
for element in iter:
    # Look for a tag called "Timeinfo"
    if element.tag == "timeinfo":
        tree = root.find(".//timeinfo")
        # Clear all tags below "timeinfo"
        tree.clear()
        element.append(ET.Element("mdattim"))
        child1 = ET.SubElement(tree, "sngdate")
        child2 = ET.SubElement(child1, "caldate1")
        child3 = ET.SubElement(child1, "caldate2")
        child4 = ET.SubElement(child1, "caldate3")
        child2.text = FIRST DATE VARIABLE GOES HERE
        child2.text = SECOND DATE VARIABLE GOES HERE
        child2.text = THIRD DATE VARIABLE GOES HERE
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your sample has an error btw, I doubt you want to set the content of child2 3 times.

Comment: Oh thanks. My mistake. I added those in when I was setting up a quick example of what I was trying to accomplish (copy and paste). You're right, they should be child2, child3, child4.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Split returns a list as follows

```
>>> a="08-26-2009;08-27-2009;08-29-2009"
>>> a_split = a.split(';')
>>> a_split
['08-26-2009', '08-27-2009', '08-29-2009']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
child2.text, child3.text, child4.text = three_dates_text.split(';')
```

Comment: This is close to what I wanted, but going forward the values in the script many vary from 3 dates to 4 or more or less. Thanks a bunch for the post.

Comment: Then amend your question please, you cannot expect us to divine the facts. Also, splicing a list is basic Python, you CoULD read the tutorial...

Answer (score 3):

When you have variables named child1, child2, child3, and child4, that is a code smell that hints that you that you should be using a list or some other kind of collection.

```
children =  [ET.SubElement(tree, "sngdate")]
children += [ET.SubElement(children[0], "caldate%s" % i) for i in xrange(3)]
```

What had been four separate variables becomes a list with four elements. Now you can go about updating the dates in each of the items:

```
dates = "08-26-2009;08-27-2009;08-29-2009"

for i, d in enumerate(dates.split(";")):
    children[i+1].date = d
```

You can adapt this to work for any number of items, even when you do not know the number of items in advance.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. Thanks for posting it. This seems to be a better approach than mine. I have a question or 2. First off if, in the first instance of "caldate" there will be a one addition tag named "time" at the same heirarchy as "caldate" but it does not occur an any addition iterations, how would I build that in? My XMl should look like this:

Comment: <timeinfo>
     <mdattim>
       <sngdate>
            <caldate>08-26-2009</caldate>
            <time>unknown</time>
        </sngdate>
      <sngdate>
            <caldate>08-27-2009</caldate>
        </sngdate>
      <sngdate>
            <caldate>08-29-2009</caldate>
        </sngdate>      
     </mdattim>
   </timeinfo>